# Dumping data from YAML file using Python

Tags: python, parsing, yaml

I have a YAML file like the following:

```
- workload:
    name: cloud1
    param:
      p1: v1
      p2: v2

- workload:
    name: cloud2
    param:
      p1: v1
      p2: v2
```

I can parse the file using the following Python script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import yaml   

try:
 for key, value in yaml.load(open('workload.yaml'))['workload'].iteritems():
   print key, value
except yaml.YAMLError as out:
  print(out)
```

output:

```
name cloud1
param {'p1': 'v1'}
```

But I'm looking for is something like:

```
workload1 = cloud1
workload1_param_p1 = v1
workload1_param_p2 = v2

workload2 = cloud2
workload2_param_p1 = v1
workload2_param_p2 = v2
```

Comment: Isn't that Yaml a tad incorrect? Shouldn't `workload` be a list?

Comment: Something like ```workloads:
  - workload: cloud1
    param:
      p1: v1
      p2: v2

  - workload: cloud2
    param:
      p1: v1
      p2: v2
```

Comment: you are right, tnx. I'll correct it.

Comment: I think this question is mislabeled as it has nothing to do with YAML.  You have a dictionary and want that data in some other form. Wether the dictionary came from parsing a YAML file or anything else entirely isn't relevant.

Comment: How about simply using the [`pprint.pprint`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pprint.html) function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your output doesn't match your input as the toplevel of your YAML file is a sequence that maps to a Python `list`.
The other thing not entirely clear is where the `workload` and especially the `1` in `workload1` come from. In the following I have assumed they come from  the key of the mapping that constitutes the sequence elements resp. the position of that sequence element (starting at 1, hence the `idx+1`).
The `name` is popped from a copy of the values, so that the rest can be recursively dumped correctly:

```
import sys
import ruamel.yaml

yaml_str = """\
- workload:
    name: cloud1
    param:
      p1: v1
      p2: v2

- workload:
    name: cloud2
    param:
      p1: v1
      p2: v2
"""

data = ruamel.yaml.round_trip_load(yaml_str)

def dump(prefix, d, out):
    if isinstance(d, dict):
        for k in d:
            dump(prefix[:] + [k], d[k], out)
    else:
        print('_'.join(prefix), '=', d, file=out)

for idx, workload in enumerate(data):
    for workload_key in workload:
        values = workload[workload_key].copy()
        # alternatively extract from values['name']
        workload_name = '{}{}'.format(workload_key, idx+1)
        print(workload_name, '=', values.pop('name'))
        dump([workload_name], values, sys.stdout)
    print()
```

gives:

```
workload1 = cloud1
workload1_param_p1 = v1
workload1_param_p2 = v2

workload2 = cloud2
workload2_param_p1 = v1
workload2_param_p2 = v2
```

This was done using [ruamel.yaml](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/ruamel.yaml), a YAML 1.2 parser, of which I am the author. If you only have YAML 1.1 code (as supported by PyYAML) you should still use `ruamel.yaml` as its round_trip_loader guarantees that your `workload_param_p1` is printed before `workload_param_p2` (with PyYAML that is not guaranteed).

Comment: For the last part, well that's a dictionary, the whole point is you normally don't care the order the keys are in. And for what it's worth, it is totally possible to have `PyYAML` spit out `OrderedDict`s, it takes about 3 lines of code to make it do so. — Note: I have nothing against your parser, it's a great piece of software, it's just this passage is both unfair and unrelated to the question.